# Github account with multiple email: Web-based activity how to

Tags: git, github

So, I am trying to find whether it is possible to configure more emails and not having a default public one to drive web-based activity but rather choose each time a web operation is done.

My problem is that I use the same account for personal (so far unfortunately few) projects and for companies one, and I would like to differentiate web-activity as I can do for local activity via `.gitconfig`.

Any idea whether it is possible to do something like that and in case how?
Here my `.gitconfig` file

```
$ git config --global -l
user.name=Bla Bla
user.email=personal.or.company@email
```

Here my web configuration:

```
personal@email
company@email Primary Public
```

The 'Public' email is always used for web-based activity and the closest I can get to my goal is to flag `Keep my email address private` (it may work but it is not quite the same).

Comment: I just ran into this issue with the same circumstance (personal GitHub used for both personal and work commits). They should let you choose which email to use per repository just like they do with the notifications settings. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: not really. I ended up just setting my email private, thus displaying only my nickname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [May 2018](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-05-03-choose-commit-email/), you now have:

> ### Choose the author email for web-based commits
>
> When making changes to files with the web-based editor, you can now choose which verified email with which to author the commit (previously you could only use your primary email).
>
> If you have [email privacy enabled](https://help.github.com/articles/about-commit-email-addresses/), the commit will be authored with your private “noreply” email.